# NullPointerException in Spring test with Service although parameter already has a value

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, service, properties

I want to test a method in service class but there is NullPointerException at line if (!uploadFolder.endsWith( "/" )) uploadFolder += "/" although uploadFolder has already a valid value. The mock value of uploadFolder in test class is taken from an application.yml file. The MockMultipartFile is also created successfully with content inside.

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class UploadService {
  private static File uploadedDocument;

  @Value("${directory.upload}")
  private String uploadFolder;

  public ResponseEntity saveFile(MultipartFile file) {
    if (!uploadFolder.endsWith( "/" )) uploadFolder += "/";
    try {
        File saveDir = new File( uploadFolder );

        if (!saveDir.exists()) {
            if (!saveDir.mkdirs())
                return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN ).body( "No permission to write." );
        }
        byte bytes[] = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get( uploadFolder + file.getOriginalFilename() );
        Files.write( path, bytes );
        File myFile = new File( uploadFolder, file.getOriginalFilename() );

        uploadedDocument = myFile;

        return ResponseEntity.status( 200 ).build();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status( 500 ).build();
}
```

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UploadServiceTest {

  private UploadService uploadService;

  @Value("${directory.upload}")
  private String uploadFolder;

  @Before
  public void before() {
    uploadService = new UploadService();
    System.out.println( uploadFolder );
  }

  @Test
  public void testSaveFile() throws Exception {
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get( uploadFolder + "\\test.txt" ) );
    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile( "document", content );
    ResponseEntity response = uploadService.saveFile( mockMultipartFile );
    Assert.assertEquals( response, new ResponseEntity( HttpStatus.ACCEPTED ) );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `uploadFolder` variable is only loaded in your test class. That's why you getting a NullPointerException. If you execute your Test, `uploadFolder` in `UploadService` is still null.

Wherever possible, i would not use spring context in a test. In your case you could run the test as a normal junit test and setting the `uploadFolder` variable of your `UploadService` with the `ReflectionTestUtils` class from spring. Add the following line to your before-method in your test-class:

```java
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(uploadService, "uploadFolder", "your_folder_path");
```

See JavaDoc of ReflectionTestUtils class: [JavaDoc: ReflectionTestUtils.setField(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

P.VAN has the point.

uploadFolder in UploadService and uploadFolder in UploadServiceTest are different objects. In this case, you can change test case like this and uploadFolder in UploadService is not null.

```
@Autowire
private UploadService uploadService;
```

And you can inject test value like this.

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"directory.upload = testDir"})
```